# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [DaoContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

Followings are my hibernate and spring jars:

> 1. hibernate-3.5.0-Final
> 2. hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Final
> 3. hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.0-Final
> 4. spring version: 4.1.6
> 5. spring-security version: 4.0.0

Comment: This is almost always a version difference between the libraries used in your build environment vs what is deployed on the server.  The method exists where you build your jar/war/ear but not where you deployed it.

Comment: You need to upgrade your hibernate libraries to 3.6.0 version atleast.

Comment: Your hibernate is **ancient** and your Spring is very recent - upgrade one or downgrade the other. Or better yet, use Spring Boot starters and let the versions be endogenous...

Comment: thanks @UmarAshraf, that problem solved but now get a another error :  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor

Comment: thanks @BoristheSpider.  that problem solved but now get a another error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor

Comment: Did you downgrade Spring or upgrade Hibernate? What are the versions you are using now?

Comment: upgrade hibernate. spring version 4.1.6 and hibernate  3.6.1 @UmarAshraf